# Print multiple variables with a macro

Tags: c, macros

I am searching a way to print (using file descriptors) multiples variables inside a unique macro, for example:

```
int   a = 2 ;
char* b = "I am a test" ;
MY_MACRO(a,b) ;
```

would display: `2 : I am a test`

But i couldn't find a way to do this, could anyone help me?

Comment: What did you try, and how did it fail? And what does this have to do with file descriptors?

Comment: It's unclear what a macro has to do with it.  Macros just expand to code, so what code do you want your macro to expand to?  Bonus question: why is it useful to write a macro for that?

Comment: A bit vague. For example, will the first parameter always be an integer and the second a `char*`?

Comment: Additionally, where's your file descriptor?

Comment: Would it be a variable number of parameters.  Does it need a format string?

Comment: Well, I'm planning to use `write(2, 'var', 'var')` with two variables so far. The types would remain the same once implemented


**EDIT:** my failures was about printing two variables, I hadn't find any elegant way to do it without many lines or without useless huge scopes of code

Comment: Never use a macro where a function will do as well! There is no need for a macro here.

Comment: `#define MY_MACRO(a, b) <%pr%:%: int ??=??=f("%\144 \72 " "%\163", a <<0X0ULL, &a<:b:>-(!!a+!!b));%>` should do the trick. Or you could indeed write a function.

Comment: Is the POSIX [`dprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dprintf.html) function an option?  If so, it'll be by far the easiest way to do what you want, and almost familiar.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can't, developpment constraint

Comment: Time to roll your own variant of `dprintf()` then — with a different name and probably simpler semantics. One issue for you: are the arguments to the macro always going to a number and a string? In most ways, it doesn't matter — you need to write a function and if you decide to call it via a macro, so be it. Presumably that allows you to control whether the printing is included in the compilation. You didn't show the file descriptor variable in the code. Does that mean it's a global variable? Or a fixed name variable such as `fd` and there simply must be an `int fd;` in scope when it's used?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a macro to write your variables to a file. I have used `stdout` for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MY_MACRO(aa,bb) fprintf(stdout,"%d: %s",aa,bb);

int main() {
    int a = 2;
    char b[] = "I am a test!";
    // your code goes here
    MY_MACRO(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's bad advice! Why not use a function?

Comment: @Olaf actualy it's almost what I want to do, I'm juste searching a way to do this using `write(1, ...` instead of `fprintf(stdout,...`

Comment: @Default: If that's what you **want**, you want a good C course, too. It definitively is not what you **should** do!

Comment: That doesn't seem to be using file descriptors.  File streams are not file descriptors.